# GridLayoutManager и RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-layout

Как правильно сделать XML разметку для одного item в RecyclerView, чтоб не было так безобразно. Чтоб не было белых мест справа и слева. И чтоб он автоматически расширялся по размеру экрана и не было бы белых мест.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_imageinterest"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:gravity="center">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/interest_checkbox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>


            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/interest_show_children"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_chevron_down"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ll_imageinterest"
            android:background="@color/dark80"
            android:paddingTop="12dp"
            android:paddingBottom="12dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Animals"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:lines="1"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/white70"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:id="@+id/interest_title"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: "белые места" убираются путем удаления margin'ов.

Comment: @NikotinN все равно не выходит, я так уже делал. У меня размер LinearLayout с id = ll_imageinterest,  ширина статичная.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не просчитал то, что отдельный item Для recyclerview нужно растягивать по всей ширине экрана. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_imageinterest"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:gravity="center">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/interest_checkbox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>


            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/interest_show_children"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_chevron_down"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/dark80"
            android:paddingTop="12dp"
            android:paddingBottom="12dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Animals"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:lines="1"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/white70"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:id="@+id/interest_title"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

А Grid LinearLayout стягивает его и размещает на экране как надо, т.е. если в коде прописано в 3 колонны, то компактно сожмет по размеру экрана.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

margin надо убрать, заменить их на padding

Comment: Разницы не будет. Тоже самое высовывается. Мне надо чтоб он растягивался и не знаю как это сделать. А место все равно остается.